# How to convert Date (long type) to the interval (example: 1 year 6 months)?

Tags: javascript, date

Here is my question. I want to convert long representation of my date (10024506364) to `1 year 3 months` (with rounding). Is it possible to do it with `Date.js`? I can't find any kind of examples how to solve this task.

Comment: But "1 year 3 month" isn't a date, it's an interval... What does 10024506364 actually represent? (It doesn't seem to represent milliseconds or seconds, at least not if it's supposed to work out at 1 year and 3 months.)

Comment: You're right. I need interval.

Comment: Perhaps you could give moment.js a go: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at momentjs http://momentjs.com/ .

```
var day = moment(1318781876406);
```

Very simple to use and has a ton of other features.